# Difuminación con CSS a un div

Tags: html, css

Quiero hacer un difuminado de un `<div>` de tal manera que quede como en la imagen. [image: Como se tendria que ver]

Intenté con las propiedades de CSS `backdrop-filter: blur(10px)` y con la propiedad `filter: blur()`, pero ninguna logró ese efecto. También probé con `box-shadow`, pero no funcionó.

Mi codigo es:

```css
body {
  /* demo, solo para ver el fondo */
  background: aqua;
}

.difuminado {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
  z-index: 15;
}
```

```html
<div class="difuminado">
  <h1>Cerrajeri y Accesorios</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se que tanto me pueda acercar a lo que buscas, pero aquí va.
Hay que jugar un poco con los valores, pero la idea es la misma.

La idea es usar `box-shadow`, pero en vez de generar 1 sombra, generamos 2.
Generamos una "default" y una `inset`, `inset` lo que hará es crear el `box-shadow` en la parte interna del div. De este modo, de manera externa le damos el efecto borroso, y de manera interna le damos el match al div con el borde borroso.

Mis valores están exagerados para que se visualice mejor, pero cambiándolos los puedes ajustar a lo deseado.

Puedes ayudarte de sitios como [este](https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/) para visualizar mejor las cosas.

```css
.difuminado {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 40px 30px rgba(139,139,139,0.7), inset 0px 0px 0px 46px rgba(139,139,139,0.64); 
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 40px 30px rgba(139,139,139,0.7), inset 0px 0px 0px 46px rgba(139,139,139,0.64);
}
```

```html
<div class="difuminado">
<h1>Cerrajeria y Accesorios</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! No sabía que se podian hacer dos box shadows. Saludos!!

Comment: De nada ;) recuerda agregar el código que usas en las preguntas que hagan a futuro en el sitio ;)